# If R is equipped with the Discrete metric, the set (0,1) is closed. Yes or no? Justify

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If R is equipped with the Discrete metric, the set (0,1) is closed. Yes or no? Justify.

On Google it says

For any subset A of a Discrete metric space, every point x in A has an open ball of radius 1/2(x) centered at x that is entirely contained within A.
This is because the open ball contains only point x and no other points from A.

{{{{{**is it because we are taking radius of 1/2 only and it is a Discrete metric so next point will be one unit away**}}}}?
Would appreciate if anyone could confirm this

Since, every point in A has an open ball entirely contained within a, A is open.

And then I understood how A complement would be open using the same logic. Thus, set will be closed.

**any other good justification?**

Comment: If a space is equipped with the discrete metric, then every singleton is open, hence every subset is open, hence every subset is closed.

Comment: Great explanation sir thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what "the" discrete metric means, I presume that you consider the

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }x\neq y\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

metric. Note that there are many, many other metrics that generate discrete spaces (meaning topology).

The main observation here is that with this metric we can look at open balls

$$B(x,r)=\{y\in X\ |\ d(x,y)<r\}$$

and if $r<1$ then

$$B(x,r)=\{x\}$$

In particular $B(x,1/2)=\{x\}$.

What this means is that singletons $\{x\}$ are open. And if singletons are open, then **all subsets** are open, since arbitrary union of open is open. And if all subsets are open, then all subsets are closed.

In particular, your $(0,1)$ inside discrete $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed.

Comment: Great explanation sir thanks alot